# How can I implement in C a function declared in a C++ namespace?

Tags: c++, c, linker, namespaces, name-mangling

Let's say I have a C++ header file `foo.hpp`:

```
namespace foo {
    int bar(int);
}
```

I cannot use `extern "C"` because it needs to only be accessible from the namespace `foo`.

Is there a portable (or relatively portable) way to declare `foo::bar` in a C file `foo.c` so that it will link with anyone using `foo::bar` from C++?

I know that on a particular system with a particular compiler, I can just find out how `foo::bar` is mangled and do something like this in `foo.c`:

```
int ZN3foo3barEi(int x) { /* ... */ }
```

But this is neither portable nor readable.

Comment: No, either you have an `extern "C" foo_bar` forwarding to `foo::bar` or drop the bar from the namespace foo and just `extern "C" foo_bar` (implementing the function)

Comment: What do you mean by "forwarding"?

Comment: Forwarding: `extern "C" int foo_bar(int x) { return foo::bar(x); }`

Comment: @DieterLücking: That's the opposite of what I'm trying to do. I think you meant `extern "C" int foo_bar(int);` and `namespace foo { int bar(int x) { return foo_bar(x); } }`

Comment: Matt: It depends, the first implementation (either C or C++) stays, the other forwards to the existing.

Comment: @DieterLücking: There is no existing implementation. It's supposed to be implemented in `foo.c`.

Answer (score 3):

`extern "C"` can be nested (in fact, that's how headers like `<cstdio>` typically work!), so you can just do the following:

```
/* C++ code */
namespace foo {
    extern "C" {
        int bar(int);
    }
}
```

After that, you just implement it in C as usual:

```
/* C code */
int bar(int x) {
    return -x; /* or whatever */
}
```

Unfortunately, if there's a naming conflict (say, if you have both `foo::bar` *and* `baz::bar`), you won't be able to have them both, unless they're the same function.

Comment: That's what I meant when I said "it needs to only be accessible from the namespace `foo`". There shouldn't be any global name `bar`, which may even conflict with other names in C. The whole point of the namespace is to prevent the name conflicts.

Comment: @Matt: In that case, no --- you'll need a wrapper function. See user590028's answer for that.

Comment: That is just a forward declaration of a function with "C" linkage - I doubt it will work as expected

Comment: @DieterLücking: What do you mean? Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: @TimČas Have you tried it (building a library and an application) using that design?

Comment: @DieterLücking: Yup. Works fine. I basically have a `namespace siege { namespace c { #include ... } }` in C++ wrapper for a C lib; there are certain issues if those C files include other (in particular stdlib) headers that I haven't gotten around to fixing --- but those are completely unrelated to any issues with function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Would a wrapper be acceptable?

```
namespace foo {
    int bar(int);
    }
extern "C" int callable_from_c(int f) {
    return foo::bar(f);
    }
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what I'm trying to do. But anyway, a wrapper would be my backup plan.

Comment: Got it.  I know you're hoping for something cleaner and I'm watching the thread myself to what you come up with (fingers crossed).

Answer (score 0):

You **are** forced to your backup plan (to use a wrapper function) for the following reason: C++ supports overloading of functions, and by that reason you can have different implementations of `bar` (with different fingerprints, even compatible) while you can have only one implementation in C.  Which of the C++ possibilities would be matched for `bar` in case you call them from C?  What if you have `bar(int)` and `bar(long)` in C++ and you want to call `bar(3)` from C?

The solution is to have one wrapper `extern "C"` function that calls the appropiate non-C function.  This function can be called from C and you'll get the desired results.

If you look, for example, at the identifier names that the linker manages, you'll see how the compiler mangles identifiers to cope at linking time with overloading.  That does not happen if you declare a function `extern "C"` in C++.

Another reason is that you don't have namespaces in C.  The C function version must be visible at the global namespace level.  You are not able to hide a C calling convention inside a namespace because it is callable from all the C code or you'll be violating the C calling conventions.

Comment: That's not a "reason", it's just an explanation of the problem.